# Google Android Layout + Code

Tags: android

What is the best way to avoid having lots of code in the main.java file when writing android apps.

it seems i will have to switch the views constantly all running through the main java file and having worker services fireing events.

am i missing something or is this how it is meant to work?

Answer (score 2):

Without more information, this is unanswerable.

The best advice now is to read the android dev guide. There is a section of best practices. You can take a look at: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/activity_task_design.html and http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/performance.html

Think about putting some code in separate threads also: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html

It's hard to understand what you mean by services firing events. The android UI is meant to be coded as objects receiving and dispatching events, and the app should respond to those evens accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, having read the dev guide on activities it makes much more sense that you have an activity that controls what should happen and a view to trigger the functionality

Answer (score 1):

Depends what kind of app you have.

Normally, different "screens" are handled by separate [**Activities**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html). Activities normally handle user input and take part in history stack (handling moving forward/back between activities and apps).

**Views** in Android are classes responsible for rendering parts of the screen. ViewGroups contain Views (and other **ViewGroups**) and are the basics of view hierarchy. View hierarchies are usually defined declaratively via XML, no coding required.

**Services** are code that run in the background without UI.

Recommended programming model is to program **asynchronously**: register handlers and code will be called when events happen. This is used not only for UI, but also for broadcasts, gps, alarms, data download, sync manager, notifications, etc..

So, Android apps are usually quite short - a 1000 lines app can already do quite a lot. Also, they tend to be nicely partitioned into distinct classes.

Comment: this is how i hoped it would work it seemed to be wrong trying to use 1 java file to co-ordiante all ui based interaction, thanks for clearing this up